# how to order the elements in relative layout

Tags: android

friend's
   I have a task to place the horizontal scroll or swipe menu tabs in my application i did it where the appears top of the header,but my problem is to place the scroll menu has below the header

### i have RelativeLayout where it contains two elements one after another,

```
       TextView   -  for header
       Gallery   -  for Scroll menu items
```

from the above code Gallery content been set from my activity,

- for example the output i'm getting

  1. looks, scroll menus(Gallery) - Header
  2. (text view defined the above layout)

========================================

- but i need it has

  1. - Header (text view defined the above layout)  -
  2. scroll menus(Gallery)

how can i get it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had read at least one time the documentation (the same way for what Maragues said, please mark question as answered when they are otherwise people will not answer you anymore) you should have seen that there are xml attributes to RelativeLayouts like android:layout_below ...

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: hi,i need your help on implementing listview with footer,where i got the view as well with footer at bottom,here the problem is where the footer hava click event to parse next page url data to bind on list view,where parsing to be good,but the list being stay back with previous page content,where the newly parsed data is not being added with list view,what is the problem,how can i fix it.just refer my question i posted with layout,i hope you may help me to get what i needed. thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a new question, this is not related to the question you asked

Answer (score 1):

Is there something about LinearLayout that makes it unsuitable?

Comment: i fixed it by using android_layout_below attribute